# How to configure SVG.js timeline in javascript to animate SVG elements along a timeline

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I am trying to get the javascript for animating an svg element along a timeline to work like i used it with SVG.js version 3.0.16 But the only available version that js fiddle has is 3.0.5

My end objective is to orchestrate multiple animations each at a different time for a different speed.

The code is as follows :

```
<div id="drawing">
<svg>
<rect id="myrect" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing');
var timeline = new SVG.Timeline();
var myrect = draw.find("#myrect").timeline(timeline);
myrect.animate(3100,100,'absolute').scale(1.3).animate(3000,100,'absolute').move(300,300);
```

My jsfiddle for the javascript i am trying to get to work is at the URL :
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/symbologysvg/ex0t9ohf/

Comment: Raise an issue on the jsfiddle github to update the svg.js version. If your code isn't working in 3.0.5 it probably means this version was buggy. You also can try to  use Codepen or any other site to do what you want

Comment: Thanks Fuzzyma I will make the request jsfiddle to include the latest SVG.js library. I will look into code pen next. The actual example i am trying to get working is more complicated but once im done with it I will post my real problem to do with moving scaling and rotating simultaneously as when i do so the svg shapes do not go to the correct positions. Thnx.

Comment: Fuzzyma, which version 3 svg.js is the most stable one for me to request jsfiddle to contain. I dont want to go in circles with the issue. Your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: You can look at npm or github to find the newest release @starrezzy.